# get value from gridview(textbox)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
   protected void OnRowCommand(object server, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) 
    { 
        int rowindex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument); 
        int fileid = Convert.ToInt32(((Label)gvAssignReviewer.Rows[rowindex].FindControl("lblFileId")‌​).Text);
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(gvAssignRequest.Rows[rowindex].Cells[0].Tex‌​t); 
        String urevid = (((TextBox)gvAssignReviewer.Rows[rowindex].FindControl("txtReviewerId")).Text); 
        ur.UpdateReviewer(fileid, urevid); 
        Bind(); 
    }
```

it's giving me FileID as it appears on the DataGrid but in the UrevID i am not getting the updated value in the textbox,hence i am getting null reference exception. please help me out.

Comment: this question is not readable. plz put more info, exactly what you do where and when, the entire process of how you try to get the data, and put code in code block (look for an icon like this "{}" in the edit mode)

Comment: protected void OnRowCommand(object server, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        int rowindex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        int fileid = Convert.ToInt32(((Label)gvAssignReviewer.Rows[rowindex].FindControl("lblFileId")).Text);
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(gvAssignRequest.Rows[rowindex].Cells[0].Text);
       
        String urevid = (((TextBox)gvAssignReviewer.Rows[rowindex].FindControl("txtReviewerId")).Text);
        
        ur.UpdateReviewer(fileid, urevid);
         Bind();
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void ASPxGridView1_CustomColumnDisplayText(object sender,  
 ASPxGridViewColumnDisplayTextEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.FieldName == "Column1")
    {
        int a= Convert.ToInt32(e.Value).ToString();
    }

    if (e.Column.FieldName == "Column2")
    {

        string b= e.Value.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the `Label` or `TextBox` is found in the `GridviewRow`. I would do it in this way:

```
protected void OnRowCommand(object server, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) 
{ 
    // Don't use Windows Message Box
    int rowindex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    var lblFileId = gvAssignReviewer.Rows[rowindex].FindControl("lblFileId") as Label;
    var txtReviewerId = gvAssignReviewer.Rows[rowindex].FindControl("txtReviewerId") as TextBox; 

    if(lblFileId != null && txtReviewerId != null)
    {
        int fileId;
        int urevId;

        if(int.TryParse(lblFileId.Text, out fileId) && int.TryParse(txtReviewerId.Text, out urevId) )
        {
                ur.UpdateReviewer(fileId, urevId); 
        }
    } 
    Bind(); 
}
```